# Reactive Network - ANdroid change default ping host

Tags: android, networking, reactive

I have application that use com.github.pwittchen.reactivenetwork.library. Cos application is meant to work in China, firewall is forbidding host: google.com.

How to change or override:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_PING_HOST = "www.google.com";
```

I can't change HOST in imported framework.
My Application.java looks like this:

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

private static boolean connected = true;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlowManager.init(new FlowConfig.Builder(this).build());

    ReactiveNetwork.observeInternetConnectivity()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Boolean isConnectedToInternet) {
                    connected = isConnectedToInternet;

                    Intent intentBatteryLvl = new Intent("RequestNetworkConnection");
                    intentBatteryLvl.putExtra("connected", isConnectedToInternet);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intentBatteryLvl);
                }
            });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but I just found this topic.
I'm the author of the ReactiveNetwork library. Since version 0.11.0, I've added `WalledGardenInternetObservingStrategy` and made it a default strategy. **Just use the latest library version** for RxJava1.x or RxJava2.x and it should work fine in China. Moreover, you can [customize ping host](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork#custom-host) in the library if you want to. Everything can be found in the [README.md](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork/blob/RxJava2.x/README.md) file

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: how to use captive portal login with your library ..please help me

Comment: I haven't tested it with captive portal login, so I'm not sure how it will work in that case and what is the correct way to solve that issue. I'd need to do more research on that.